# How to install X11 (VNC VIEWER) in Ubuntu 18.04 and above to take system in remote with graphical interface?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, gui, remote, vncviewer

Please help me to install X11 VNC VIEWER with graphical login screen in 18.04 and above.

Answer (score 0):

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get install lightdm

#Click on OK and select lightdm in gui

3. sudo reboot
4. sudo apt-get install x11vnc
5. sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/x11vnc.service

#Next copy below and save

[Unit]
Description=x11vnc service
After=display-manager.service network.target syslog.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -forever -display :0 -auth guess -passwd password
ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall x11vnc
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

6. systemctl daemon-reload
7. systemctl enable x11vnc.service
8. systemctl start x11vnc.service

Note : Password will be password by default you can change by editing x11vnc service. if you change password restart the service.